# Select the column with highest value using R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape, reshape2

I have a `dataframe` like this:

```
salesDat

id    time    amount
1     12       100
1     14       120
1     22       120
2     5        30
2     12       30
3     40       3
3     75       20
3     80       20
3     85       75
```

**What do I want?**

I want to find the `max` `time` value and only use that value so that the `id` column is unique.

eg: the new `dataframe` will look like this

```
salesDat

id    time    amount
1     22       120
2     12       30
3     85       75
```

**What did I do?**

I used `reshape2` package

```
library(reshape2)

uniqueSalesDat <- dcast(salesDat, 
                  id~time)
```

The code does not work. How do I fix it?

Comment: `aggregate(.~id, df, max)` Or `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(max)` in `dplyr`.

Comment: Thanks!, how do I deal with `na` values in the `time` column?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(max, na.rm  =TRUE)`

Comment: I am getting this now: `Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 2L, 1L, : ‘max’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: `df %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(max, na.rm =TRUE)`

Comment: It removes that `factor` error but I still do not get `max` of `time` group by `id`

Comment: Then please add data using `dput` in your post. It works fine for me at my end and gives the exact expected output if I use this data `structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), time = c(12L, 
14L, 22L, 5L, 12L, 40L, 75L, 80L, 85L), amount = c(100L, 120L, 
120L, 30L, 30L, 3L, 20L, 20L, 75L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))`